# In windows phone, How to do "Clicking on back button should close the app"?

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-phone-8

Hi i am working on one app having menupage.If user is in menupage and press back button of the phone, I want the application to be closed. Currently if i am pressing back button it navigates to previous pages.

Please Help me, Genuine help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the BackStack on that page (ideally in OnNavigatedTo)

```
while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
{
   this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code when you need to close your application.

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

Comment: IMO this should be avoided and used rarely as possible. Of course when used, it should be handeled properly along with lifetime and other events/methods/tasks/processes.

Comment: yes and should be the last statement executing in your Application.